# Postgres join as inner json

Tags: postgresql, join, json

Just trying to do a simple inner join as **json**.

**model**

```
posts (author is fk to profiles.id)
  id
  author
  title
  ...
profiles
  id
  displayName
  ...
```

Trying to do a simple join so that:

```sql
select * from posts
(join profiles on profiles.id = posts.author -- as json?)
```

so that my result would look like:

| id | title | author | .. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | some title 1 | { id: 02xx, displayName: 'Jon', username: 'jon1' } |  |
| 2 | some title 2 | { id: 02xx, displayName: 'Jon', username: 'jon1' } |  |

I feel like there is a very simple way to do this?

J

Answer (score 1):

Well I seem to have found two ways to do this, although I imagine there are many. If you know of another way, please post it here.

**array_to_json()**

```sql
select posts.*, array_to_json(array_agg(profiles.*)) as author from posts
join profiles on profiles.id = posts.author
group by posts.id
```

Not sure why I need group by here, but this is good if you're joining several items.

**row_to_json()**

```sql
select posts.*, row_to_json(profiles.*) as author from posts
join profiles on profiles.id = posts.author
```

This seems to be the best in my use case.

Please most more if you know of them!

Thanks,

J